# About an impossibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose Goldbach conjecture true:
$\forall{n\geq{9}}$ integer, $\exists{p_1\geq{3},p_2\geq{3}}$ primes for which $2n=p_1+p_2$.

But
$\forall{m>1}$ integer, $\forall{p_1\geq{3},p_2\geq{3}}$ primes, 
$2(4m+1)\neq{2p_1+2p_2}$ 
and $\forall{k,k'\neq{0}}$ integers
$2(4m+3)\neq{2p_1+8k+2p_2+8k'}$. 
Thus 
$$2(4m+3-4m-1)=4\neq{2p_1+8k+2p_2+8k'-2p_1-2p_2}=8(k+k')$$ 
Or
$$2(4m+3+4m+1)=2(8m+4)\neq{2p_1+8k+2p_2+8k'+2p_1+2p_2}.$$
It means that $\exists{m>1}$ integer, $\forall{p_1\geq{3},p_2\geq{3}}$ primes 
$1\neq{2(k+k')}$ which is always verified.
Or there exists $m,k,k'$ for which (I am not sure about the existence of $m$)
$4m+2-2k-2k'=2(2m+1-k-k')\neq{p_1+p_2}$.
It means that there exists an even which is never equal to the sum of two primes ! 
Is this reasoning correct ? I suppose there is a fault, where is it, please ? Thank you !

Comment: Why don't you say $\forall n \geq 1$ is my first question.  (that's Goldbach's conjecture).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture

Comment: Please prove the statements in your Third sentence.  I think that's where the error is

Answer (score 1):

You say: for all $m \gt 1$ and primes $p_1, p_2 \geq 3$, we have $2(4m + 1) \neq 2 p_1 + 2 p_2$ which is true, and that additionally, for all $k, k' \neq 0$, we have $2(4m+3) \neq 8(k + k') + 2(p_1 + p_2)$, which is also true since you can divide by $2$ and subtract $4(k+k')$ and we have that the lhs is odd and the rhs even.

But we cannot conclude that for all $k, k'$ your third sentence is true since in general $A \neq B$ and $C \neq D$ doesn't imply $A - C \neq B - D$, and similarly goes for $+$.  In your third sentence though, the below happens to be true:

$$
2(4m+3-4m-1)=4\neq{2p_1+8k+2p_2+8k'-2p_1-2p_2}
$$

Let's look at the second part:

$$
2(4m+3+4m+1)=2(8m+4)\neq{2p_1+8k+2p_2+8k'+2p_1+2p_2}.
$$

It's true iff we cancel the $2$'s and that's true.  So we have:
$$
8m+4 \neq {8(k+k')+2(p_1 + p_2)}.
$$

That is what I don't think is true.